# Sendgrid to stop changing plain text links?

Tags: python, sendgrid

How to tell sendgrid to stop decorating plain text URLs?

Using sendgrid SDK for Python, if that matters.

```
sendgrid.SendGridClient(username, pwd)
mail = sendgrid.Mail()
mail.set_html(html_message)
mail.set_text(text_message_with_urls)  # <-- urls are here
...
sendgrid_client.send(mail)
```

For HTML-side this already has an answer:

[Is it possible to exclude links from tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873632/is-it-possible-to-exclude-links-from-tracking)

Tracking still needed for HTML parts of mails.

Comment: Turn off click tracking in your SendGrid settings in the portal.

Comment: that is still needed, but not on everything in plain text. THe setting most probably will affect html as well. updated question

Comment: Yes, we use that setting to turn off click-tracking in our HTML emails. Our users have been suspicious when they hover over html links and the URL doesn't match the link we say they can paste manually.

Comment: it's a different case, not this question. We need click-tracking in HTML mails, but not in plain text ones.

Comment: Then I think you may be out of luck. I don't think there's a way to customize it on per-message basis, and only HTML has attributes to control it in the anchor.

Comment: You could try asking SendGrid Tech Support, I generally find them helpful.

Comment: Ok. I will report the results here if no-one answer first.

Comment: any results? I have a similar problem

Comment: No results. Seems like support was not contacted, can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I contacted support and they informed me that I could use [Clicktrack SMTP filter](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/smtp-filters/#filter-clicktrack) with the `X-SMTPAPI` header.

There are two filter options, one is the enable and disable the click-tracking setting and the other for enabling or disabling click-tracking links in the Plain-Text portion of the message.

The Sendgrid Python client has helper class ClickTracking to control these settings:

```py
import json
import os

from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *

sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
from_email = Email("team@example.com")
to_email = To("test@example.com")
subject = "Sending with ClickTracking plain text disabled"
content = Content(MimeType.text, "Test URL: https://www.google.com")
message = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)

tracking_settings = TrackingSettings()
tracking_settings.click_tracking = ClickTracking(enable=True, enable_text=False)
message.tracking_settings = tracking_settings

response = sendgrid_client.send(message=message)
print(response.status_code)
```

A flask-mail example setting the `X-SMTPAPI' header with clicktrack filter:

```py
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_mail import Message

mail = Mail(app)
subject = "Sending with clicktrack plain text disabled"
body = "Test URL: https://www.google.com"
headers = {"X-SMTPAPI": json.dumps({
  "filters" : {
    "clicktrack" : {
      "settings" : {
        "enable" : 1,
        "enable_text" : False
      }
    }
  }
})}
message = Message(subject=subject, body=body, extra_headers=headers)
mail.send(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable click tracking in settings: [Disable clicktracting in sendgrid](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/tracking)

This feature is there to track clicks as the name says. By default sendgrid also adds An invisible image is being appended to HTML emails to track if they have been opened.